# Styling of labels not responding to CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, text-styling

Basic form and labels.

```css
label {
  margin-top: 1em; /*or padding-top: 20em or any em changes nothing*/
  margin-left: 2em /* padding-left: 20em or any em actually applies the styles*/
}

input {
  margin: 4em; /* or padding: in any amount works.  */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="question">Content</label>
  <input type="text" value="anything"></input>
  <form>
```

my question is why doesn't the padding and margin work for the label.  After sometime I finally realized I needed to make the label an block element and then it works but that doesn't sit well with me or make sense.  I didn't have to do that for styles to apply to input and in all the tutorials I saw no one ever explicitly said label display block so I am wondering why this behavior? I thought it might be because the element (label) doesn't recognize content around it since it is not a block element but that makes less sense than the fact it does not work as expected.   Any CSS gurus understand why this behavior is happening with the label element?

Comment: The styling you've added appears to be working. The HTML is invalid (`input` does not have a closing tag, and the second `<form>` is probably meant to be `</form>` as you are not allowed to nest `form` elements in HTML. Note that `for` should have a value that is identical to the `id` attribute of the element it is labeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention, the label will need to have a `display` property value of `block` or preferably `inline-block` for this to take effect. The reason you didn't have to do this explicitly with the `input` element is that input is an `inline-block` by default. `label`, on the other hand, is `inline` by default, so you'll have to manually declare it to be `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. thank you. I never thought to check the default styles.  Was causing much frustration.